# Picker does not refresh after adding new item to the list

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking to update the content of Picker dynamically. For example load the list of a Picker after the view appears. Below is the sample code, but does not work as expected. The expected behavior is:

- After clicks the "Add Yellow" button, the "yellow" shows up in the list and the picker.

The observation is:

- After clicks the "Add Yellow" button, the "yellow" shows up in the list but not the picker.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

Thanks

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selection = 0
    @State var colors: [String] = ["red", "blue", "green"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Color")) {
                ForEach(self.colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    Text(color)
                }
            }

            List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
            }) {
                Text("Add Yellow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / 13.4

```
Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Color")) {
    ForEach(self.colors, id: \.self) { color in
        Text(color)
    }
}.id(colors)      // << here !!
```